# VBA: Optimal way to select Top Left cell of selection

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to find the best way to select the top left cell from a selection. The current code looks too bulky to be the optimal way:

```
Sub CAIShowHandle()

    Dim TopLeftColumn As String
    Dim TopLeftRow As String

    'changing to only top left cell
    With Selection
        TopLeftRow = .Row
        TopLeftColumn = Col_Letter(.Column)
    End With
    Range(TopLeftColumn & TopLeftRow).Select

End Sub
```

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: `Range("A1:XCD1000").Cells(1, 1)` will give you  `Range("A1")`, In your case: `Selection.Cells(1, 1).Select` would do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do when you have a selection:

```
Selection(1).Select
```

However, be carefull using `.Select` as it can mostly be avoided. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) post on StackOverflow for more clarification on that subject.

Comment: So simple! Worked a treat! Thanks

Comment: This won't work with selections of multiple areas where the top left cell is not in the first area